# Horizontal ScrollView within Vertical ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, vertical-scrolling

I am developing a fragment with HorizontalScrollView of ImageView in android. I want to implement a vertical ScrollView as parent and HorizontalScrollView as its child. How can i implement this? Here is my .xml file with HorizontalScrollView :-

```
<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<SearchView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/searchView"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:textStyle = "bold|italic"
    android:queryHint="@string/search"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="#ffffff" />

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/LoginFormContainer"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/picture1" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/picture2" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/picture3" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/picture6" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/hospital" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/picture7" />

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ScrollView` class is for vertical scrolling so:

```
<SearchView
.../>
    <ScrollView
    .../>
        <HorizontalScrollView
        .../>
            <LinearLayout
            .../>
                <!-- Multiple views here -->
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </ScrollView>
</SearchView>
```

Comment: And suppose if i add some textViews in the interface then the idea you gave,is not working as a scrollView can't host more than one child view. Do you have solution for this?

Comment: @AyushGupta I edited my answer, just use a `LinearLayout` as you did in your code.